# Has anyone been able to get TriggerIO to work with parse push notifications?

Tags: trigger.io

I'm not able to get any push notifications out to my android emulator.
I go to the Parse admin console and send out a push, but it shows as no subscribers and nothing ever happens on my emulator.

I was hoping someone could share a bit of code showing how they were able to push out?

I've set up my client and rest api keys, and am able to send a picture to Parse via the demos I've followed. But when trying to push back to the client it doesn't work...

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Hojoki is an example:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hojoki/id525010205?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

If you use messagePushed.addListener, you'll be automatically subscribed to the default channel:

```
forge.event.messagePushed.addListener(function (msg) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
});
```

Have you entered your applicationId and clientKey as described [here](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/partners/parse.html#configuring-push-notifications)?

**Note**: it's your *client* key, not REST key, that you need to enter in that configuration.