# Push Notifications for Android app using Trigger.io and Parse are not working

Tags: trigger.io

Push Notifications for my Android app using Trigger.io and Parse are not working.  Everything seems to be set up correctly in Parse and Trigger, Parse says the pushes are going through but the phone never receives them regardless if the app is open or not.  I have another part of the app that successfully uploads photos to Parse and uses the REST API to pull them back down and I see my single installation in the dashboard assigned to my beta channel.  Neither the Broadcast nor the specific channel seems to work. I'm just wondering if there is a setting on the device or in my config file that I need to switch to allow the push notifications to go through.  All documentation I can find still references the forge.partners.parse functions which are no longer in use and the syntax seems to be a bit different around this functionality now.  Any help is appreciated!!

I found something that could be a factor, my AndroidManifest seems to be missing a couple things that are show on the Parse documentation(here: https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications ), I can't directly edit this XML file because Trigger compiles it automatically so I'm not sure what I can do.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="io.trigger.forge44c192547c6611e3b1811231392b77b0" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1391094815" android:versionName="0.1">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="TheFireStore App" android:name="io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeApp">
    <activity android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|fontScale|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeActivity" android:stateNotNeeded="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="TheFireStore.com" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider android:authorities="io.trigger.forge44c192547c6611e3b1811231392b77b0" android:exported="true" android:name="io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeContentProvider" tools:ignore="ExportedContentProvider" />
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10499911/1737472 ?

Comment: I wish it did, I have my listener in place but it just isn't hearing anything.